# Get Web App root from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, file-io

I am trying to write an uploaded multipart file to the filesystem.  I have a directory called audio which sits in the root of my web application (not inside WEB-INF, but beside it, to it's publicly accessible like css and javascript).

I want to write the uploaded file to that directory but I can't seem to get the path I need.  I thought getting a ServletContext() then using realPath() may work, but I don't have a reference to ServletContext through a Spring controller.  Thanks for any hep

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadSample")
public ModelAndView upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile f) {

    if (f == null) {
        return new ModelAndView("upload", "msg", "The file is null.");
    }
    try {
        // I need to set AUDIO_PATH to <webAppRoot>/audio
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(AUDIO_PATH + "/" + f.getOriginalFilename());
        file.write(f.getBytes());
        file.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SampleUploadController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SampleUploadController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



   return new ModelAndView("upload", "msg", "File ( " + f.getOriginalFilename() + ") successfully uploaded.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I thought getting a ServletContext()
>   then using realPath() may work, but I
>   don't have a reference to
>   ServletContext

Yes you do.  See [HttpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getServletContext%28%29)

Comment: This won't work, however, if you don't have a session and wish to remain sessionless.  See the answer from axtavt.

Answer (score 27):

To get reference to `ServletContext`, your class can implement [ServletContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html)

`ServletContext` is also accessible in the web application container under the bean name `servletContext`, so you can inject it like any other bean in Spring. This works even if you don't have a session, and dependency injection is the Spring way.

Comment: not working. in case i am not inside a servlet... i get the "context" object, but getContextPath returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Getting server url using `ServletContext` is not safe across different environments.

It would be better to retrieve the url from a property file.