# Spring MVC @RestController and redirect

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, redirect, http-redirect

I have a REST endpoint implemented with Spring MVC @RestController. Sometime, depends on input parameters in my controller I need to send http redirect on client.

Is it possible with Spring MVC @RestController and if so, could you please show an example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311940/redirect-to-dynamic-url-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Your linked post is NOT for ```@RestController``` classes because it includes ```@ResponseBody```. Your "redirect:" string would not be interpreted as a view.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Add an `HttpServletResponse` parameter to your Handler Method then call `response.sendRedirect("some-url");`

Something like:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

  @RequestMapping("/foo")
  void handleFoo(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendRedirect("some-url");
  }

}
```

Comment: Sadly this looks like the only solution. I was also hoping there is a nicer way without a HttpServletResponse parameter.

Comment: @MajidLaissi - actually, it is quite sad.  For the most part, it is possible to entirely abstract Spring MVC controllers away from any dependency on HTTP as a transport protocol at all, but that is unfortunately not possible here.

Comment: I like both this solution and the one by @Arne Burmeister but neither of them solve my problem of browser not handling the redirect (HTTP 302) of a XHR request's response because of reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: This is `302`, how about return `301` ?

Comment: there is, instead of a `@RestController` use a `@Controller` and a method returning a `String` as your template f.i. `return "redirect:/mytemplate"`

Comment: @PhillAlexakis, sometimes it could be app without configured ViewResolver (rest api, for example) and in that case you could not use redirect in such way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71886060/6637228

Answer (score 91):

To avoid any direct dependency on `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse` I suggest a "pure Spring" implementation returning a [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) like this:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setLocation(URI.create(newUrl));
return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
```

If your method always returns a redirect, use `ResponseEntity<Void>`, otherwise whatever is returned normally as generic type.

Comment: Or in one line `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY).header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, newUrl).build();`

Comment: Does newUrl in this case have to be a fully qualified URL?  If so, this solution would be clunky at best when redirecting to another URL in your app, because you would have to build the entire URL.  Using HttpServletResponse allows you to send a redirect relative to the servlet container root.

Comment: and it works like a charm if you use swagger client generation code ;-)

Comment: I am trying to add a custom header in this along with "location", but its not working any idea? @Arne

Comment: What about sending @RequestBody when redirecting?

Comment: @MartinMaťovčík what should be the meaning of a response body for a redirect (I assume you meant response instead of request body as I would get no sense the other way around)?

Answer (score 28):

Came across this question and was surprised that no-one mentioned RedirectView. I have just tested it, and you can solve this in a clean 100% spring way with:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public RedirectView handleFoo() {
        return new RedirectView("some-url");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to set the url with the context path?

Comment: @Bahij.Mik I'm assuming you're asking about the servlet context path -- the following tells me that you can autowire the servlet context and retrieve the path from it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236590/retrieving-the-servlet-context-path-from-a-spring-web-application#15084082)

Answer (score 5):

`redirect` means http code `302`, which means `Found` in springMVC.

Here is an util method, which could be placed in some kind of `BaseController`:

```
protected ResponseEntity found(HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException { // 302, found, redirect,
    response.sendRedirect(url);
    return null;
}
```

---

But sometimes might want to return http code `301` instead, which means `moved permanently`.

In that case, here is the util method:

```
protected ResponseEntity movedPermanently(HttpServletResponse response, String url) { // 301, moved permanently,
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY).header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, url).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the redirections are usually needed in a not-straightforward path, I think throwing an exception and handling it later is my favourite solution.

Using a ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler
    extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = {
      NotLoggedInException.class
  })
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotLoggedIn(
      final NotLoggedInException ex, final WebRequest request
  ) {
    final String bodyOfResponse = ex.getMessage();

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Location", ex.getRedirectUri());
    return handleExceptionInternal(
        ex, bodyOfResponse,
        headers, HttpStatus.FOUND, request
    );
  }
}
```

The exception class in my case:

```
@Getter
public class NotLoggedInException extends RuntimeException {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4900004519786666447L;

  String redirectUri;

  public NotLoggedInException(final String message, final String uri) {
    super(message);
    redirectUri = uri;
  }
}
```

And I trigger it like this:

```
if (null == remoteUser)
  throw new NotLoggedInException("please log in", LOGIN_URL);
```

Answer (score -12):

if you @RestController returns an **String** you can use something like this

```
return "redirect:/other/controller/";
```

and this kind of redirect is only for **GET** request, if you want to use other type of request use HttpServletResponse

Comment: It will work only for `@Controller` but not for the `@RestController` which is a specialized version of `@Controller` and add `@ResponseBody` annotation.  Spring Framework will convert the return value and write it to the http response automatically. `@RestController
public class RedirectController {

    @RequestMapping("/redirect")
    public String redirect() {
        return "redirect:/other/controller/";
    }

}`  and if we will try to access that url  `curl localhost:8080/redirect`  we will simply see `redirect:/other/controller/` string as result.

Comment: Anton Balaniuc is right, and reading your whole answer still is not right. In a RestController it will just return the String "redirect:/other/controller", it will not redirect