# Spring boot single page application - forward every request to index.html

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot (v1.3.6) single page application (angular2) and i want to forward all request to the `index.html`.

A request to http://localhost:8080/index.html is working (200 and i get the index.html) but http://localhost:8080/home is not (404).

Runner.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"packagea.packageb"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(Runner.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebAppConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    private static final int CACHE_PERIOD_ONE_YEAR = 31536000;

    private static final int CACHE_PERIOD_NO_CACHE = 0;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setOrder(-1);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles.css").addResourceLocations("/styles.css").setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD_ONE_YEAR);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/third-party/**").addResourceLocations("/node_modules/").setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD_ONE_YEAR);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/").setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD_NO_CACHE);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/systemjs.config.js").addResourceLocations("/systemjs.config.js").setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD_NO_CACHE);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/index.html").setCachePeriod(CACHE_PERIOD_NO_CACHE);
    }

}
```

`styles.css`, `/app/third-party/xyz/xyz.js`,.. are working (200 and i get the correct file). Only `/**` to `index.html` is not working.

Comment: maybe index.html is in a protected folder or in other path?

Comment: @duardito the `index.html` is in the same folder (`webapp`) as `styles.css`

Comment: do you have an endpoint matching "/home"?

Comment: @duardito No i have no endpoint matching `/home`

Comment: so, if there is no matching resource to "/home" , i think it is normal this 404 error because this page doesn't exists, and no endpoint in your backend is matching "/home", so everytime to make a request to your backend with "/home"  you will get 404 error, because there is no matching endpoint.

Comment: My goal was to match with `/**` every request and forward them to `index.html`.

Answer (score 44):

You can also add a forwarding controller like:

```
@Controller
public class ForwardingController {
    @RequestMapping("/{path:[^\\.]+}/**")
    public String forward() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

The first part `{path:[^\\.]+}` matches one or more of any character other than `.`. This makes sure request for a `file.ext` doesn't get handled by this RequestMapping. If you need to support sub-paths to also be forwarded, put `/**` outside of the `{...}`.

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex for an explanation of the {varName:regex} form allowing more complicated regex-based matching.

Comment: Since I forward my requests to "/ui/index.html", I had to adjust the path mapping to "/**/{path:[^\\.]+}" in order to avoid stack overflow exception due to it matching paths which have a period character in the last component.

Comment: `"/{path:[^\\.]+}/**"` can't handle static files in subdirectories. `"/**/{path:[^\\.]+}"` works fine

Comment: Best answer ever!

Comment: @basil the expression `"/**/{path:[^\\.]+}"` does not work anymore with spring boot 2.6.. It states: `Invalid mapping pattern detected: /**/{path:[^\\.]+}, No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element`

Answer (score 5):

This one didn't work for me:

```
return "forward:/";
```

Thanks to [Spring MVC @RestController and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect) I found a nicely working solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendRedirect("/");
}
```

Comment: You need Thymeleaf templating for "forward:/" to work.

Answer (score 3):

Without looking at logs I'm not entirely sure why its not being mapped correctly, however if you want to map URLs to a view (HTML) then you will probably be better off using the `viewController` mechanism spring provides http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller.  e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
  }

}
```

(taken from spring docs linked above - this is how you should map a url to a view rather than re-purposing the mapping for static resources.)

I'm not sure if there is any kind of suffix filtering for the resource mapping - e.g. I don't know how spring decides to map requests to the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` - have you tried (just to confirm or deny) whether something like http://localhost:8080/home.html amps to anything?

It's also possible that the html mapping you have defined above is just being ignored and the index.html is just working because of Spring-Boot's default home page behaviour: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ResourceProperties.java#L108

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the following worked for me. My html files are inside src/main/resources/static/app

The key was to remove @EnableWebMvc and add "classpath:/static/app/" to addResourceLocations! Hope this helps.

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/","classpath:/static/app/", "classpath:/public/" };

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
            }
            if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                        CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            // forward requests to /admin and /user to their index.html
            registry.addViewController("/portal").setViewName(
                    "forward:/app/index.html");
        }
    };
}
```