# Angular CLI - Images not showing after 'ng build'

Tags: javascript, image, angular

When I run `ng build` I have a problem. I try to load some image to my page, but these images are not shown. My console not is not throwing any 404 errors. All of my images are place in `assets` folder.

```
<div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <img src="assets/img/people/user-1.png" alt="user" />
</div>
```

But if I run command `ng serve` it's works fine.
Thank you for all your answers.

Here is my `.angular.cli.json` file

```
`{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../src/main/webapp",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}`
```

Comment: did you verify if you build folder in location `../src/main/webapp` contains assets folder and a sub folder of img?

Comment: yes, of course, my application is building to `../src/main/webapp/` folder. Here is my screenshot of `webapp` folder http://imgur.com/a/ktx0w

Comment: what is the src=, when you view source, of your image?

Comment: it has been written at the top of my post

Comment: oh sorry. I thought maybe it was what you saw in your ide, and maybe the src changes in the browser.

Comment: I got same error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the problem with the server. 
If you are trying to open your page by click on index.html, it will work only with js files without assets.

How do you start your server after build?

Comment: First of all I build the Angular project to the `webapp` folder and then I run the Spring Boot application

Comment: How I know Spring boot is server side application. Could you try run your application with nginx, apache or sth?
Of course, best practice shows that output application shouldn't be in src. e.g. for coverage.

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same to me, and the problem was that I was [forwarding requests on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625064/8339239), so that the user was able to enter the application in a specific route. (I mean, for example, http://myangularapp.com/profile)

In my case, I built a jar with both a spring boot backend and an angular frontend and therefore needed that trick to allow angular to resolve the routes.

I believe something changed recently with angular-cli or angular, since I already used that strategy before and it was working fine.

By the way, this happened with "@angular/cli": "^1.2.0".