# Change the request method from POST to GET in a redirection from spring controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, web

I have a spring mvc controller, which accepts a post request and it needs to redirect to a URL (GET request).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sredirect", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Ews redirect hit !!! ");
request.setAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE,HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    
    return "redirect:https://www.google.com/";
}
```

And the class is annotated with @RestController. I am always getting 405, method not allowed for the redirect url. (i.e google.com).

As per docs (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7238), it should allow the method to be changed . I am not sure what am I doing wrong? Can someone help

Comment: It sounds like you're getting the 405 instead of your logging, correct? Are you doing an HTTP POST to your /sredirect? That's the only thing this controller will accept.

Comment: No , my logs are being printed correctly in console, .

Comment: Ok, based on this, then, I'm thinking that RestControllers can't simply return "redirect:", like non-Rest Controllers can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect (Not adding as an answer, because I don't actually know :-))

Comment: @dbreaux You are correct, the solution mentioned in the link works for me. You can add this as answer, I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Rest Controllers can't use the simple "redirect:" convention, like non-Rest Controllers can. See [Spring MVC @RestController and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accepting GET in the request mapping?

```
method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }
```

Comment: Hmm Okay. Maybe change the function to return type void and call `request.sendRedirect("https://www.google.com");` instead of the return.