# How to make REST api that can redirect to url in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have created a REST api which can used to save different urls those url have auto-increment feature that assign them an id one endpoint is to add urls and other is to fetch urls from id
I want to do something like if I pass localhost:8080/getUrlById?id=4/ my browser should redirect me to that url which is there at 4th no.

my controller code -

```
@GetMapping("/addUrl")
public ResponseEntity<?> addUrlByGet(String url) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(sortnerService.addUrlByGet(url),HttpStatus.OK);
}


@GetMapping("/findUrlById")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findSortnerById(Integer id){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(sortnerService.findUrlById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

service class -

```
@Service
public class SortnerService {
    @Autowired
    private  SortnerRepo sortnerRepo;

    public Sortner addUrlByGet(String url) {
        Sortner sortner = new Sortner();
        sortner.setUrl(url);
        return  sortnerRepo.save(sortner);
    }

//   finding by particular Id

   public List<Sortner> findUrlById(Integer id){
        return sortnerRepo.findSortnerById(id);
   }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me any way to do it I am really new to SpringBoot Sorry if I have made any silly mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC @RestController and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect)

Comment: Yes  I was looking into this but here most of the answers are simply redirecting to some static url not from the id chosen by the client.

Comment: @VadymVL can you please suggest me some way how to redirect to the particular link that is existing in the db as long as user ask for url at id=1 the respective url should redirect I hope you are getting my point !

Comment: What does a `Sortner` class? You need to convert you Sortner class to a URL

Comment: Sortner is nothing just a weird name (maybe it means something idk) its model class contain two private variables id which is autoincrement and url to set and get url , getter and setters and nothing much,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information from the comments, I suggest that the `Sortner` class looks like this:

```
  public class Sortner {
    Long id;
    URL url;
  }
```

So to redirect to the URL by the Id from your service you need to rewrite your controller to look like this:

```
  @GetMapping("/findUrlById")
  public void findSortnerById(Integer id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    List<Sortner> urls = sortnerService.findUrlById(id);
    if(urls != null && urls.size() > 0) {
        response.sendRedirect(urls.get(0).getUrl().toString());
    }
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
  }
```

- [response.sendRedirect](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int)) redirects to the required URL
- [response.sendError](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int)) returns 404 as the URL cannot be found in the database

Comment: Thank you soo much I think now I got the idea how this works, This really means a lot :D just last thing its url is just appended with my application url like - localhost:8080/google.com is there any solution :) sorry for asking too much Thanks again

Comment: To prevent appending to your application URL like - `localhost:8080/google.com`, you need to ensure that the URL that you are redirecting has a schema section `http://` or `https://`. If t doesn't, you need to add it manually before calling `sendRedirect`.
For example `response.sendRedirect("https://google.com");`

Comment: If you are calling this API as a document from a browser, the redirection will work. However, if this GET API call comes from Javascript, the redirection will not work.