# Openapi Generator. How to generate method with HttpServletResponse as parameter?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, openapi, spring-restcontroller, openapi-generator

everyone.

I use strategy "Design first". I describe specification.
One of the methods accepts HttpServletResponse as paramether.
But i don't know ho to describe it correctly in my .yaml-fle.

What i tried to write:

```
/api/method:
    get:
      tags:
        - XXXController
      summary: ~
      description: ~
      operationId: doSomething
      parameters:
        - description: HttpServletResponse
          in: query
          name: response
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpServletResponse'
```

- 

In the same time, i added ImportMappings to the build.gradle:

```
importMappings = [
                     HttpServletResponse: "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse"
    ]
```

And it doesn't work.

if i place to $ref "real" component, which is described in "components" section - it will be OK.

But it doesn't work with external classes (mapped in importMappings)

I need your help

i expect to get method like this

```
public void method(HttpServletResponse response);
```

but i recieve an error:

```
Errors: 
  -attribute paths.'/method/l'(get).parameters.[response].schemas.#/components/schemas/HttpServletResponse is missing
```

Answer (score 3):

`HttpServletResponse` is not something you want to add to the OpenAPI description.

Someone calling your api via http will be very confused about it and won't be able to provide a framework specific java class as parameter.

`HttpServletResponse` is something you get from your Spring Boot application, e.g. like in your example above. It is an implementation detail.

Since `HttpServletResponse` it is not part of the API and you don't have direct control over the signature of the generated api method the generator must provide code to access the `HttpServletResponse`.

I'm not an openapi-generator expert, but using a small test project it generates code like this:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${openapi.sample.base-path:}")
public class FooApiController implements FooApi {

    private final NativeWebRequest request;

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    public FooApiController(NativeWebRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(request);
    }
}
```

You can then use `NativeRequest` from your endpoint implementation to get the response object.

...

[openapi-processor](https://docs.openapiprocessor.io/oap/home/home.html) (I'm the author) is an alternative generator that's using a different way to provide access to `HttpServletResponse`.

Having an api:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: test additional endpoint parameters
  version: 1.0.0

paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: foo
          description: query, required
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '204':
          description: empty
```

and a few extra lines of configuration:

```yaml
# snippet from the yaml configuration

  paths:
    /foo:
      parameters:
        - add: response => javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
```

it will generate a (interface) method with an additional `HttpServletResponse` parameter:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/foo")
void getFoo(@RequestParam(name = "foo") String foo, HttpServletResponse response);
```

Comment: i just tried. but it din't work.

Comment: `org.openapitools.codegen.SpecValidationException: There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI).
 | Error count: 1, Warning count: 1
Errors: 
 -attribute paths.'/videos2Csv/{id}'(get).parameters.[['unknown']].in is missing
Warnings: 
 -attribute paths.'/videos2Csv/{id}'(get).parameters.[['unknown']].in is missing`

Comment: There is a validation error in your OpenAPI. Looks like there is an errror  in the id parameter description.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved by injecting `HttpServletResponse` with `@autowired`, not as method parameter