Base URL for Spring Boot and handle / as well
I would like to set the context path for the Spring Boot application, and the following property can achieve that.
server.contextPath=/api

However, I would like to redirect / to /api. Currently, I am getting a HTTP 404 Error. How can I achieve that in Spring Boot?

You can use reverse proxy like Nginx to do that.

if you don't want to use nginx, you can do it in spring boot as well - this has been asnwered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect

(1) With Spring Boot, inside application.properties (or somehthing like this in application.yml)
server.servlet.context-path=/api

(2) or
server.context-path=/api

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#:~:text=parameters.a%3Dalpha-,server.context%2Dpath,-%3D%20%23%20the%20context
(3)
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api

See

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67922089/3728901

Let's share with me your result.
